# Has the Green Arrow gone on a different planet?

Tags: dc, comics, green-arrow

Green Arrow is a character who doesn't possess any superpower other than his fighting skills and willpower. He generally has fights with Earth based villains. But the other members of Justice League has gone on different planets to fight the villains, like Apokolips, etc. Has Green Arrow ever gone to any other planet (not any other version of Earth)? If yes in which comics issue?

Comment: Too often to count. Notably when teamed up with Green Lantern https://www.amazon.co.uk/Green-Lantern-Arrow-Traveling-Heroes/dp/1401295533

Comment: He was with the rest of the heroes in their attempt to defeat Dr. Manhattan on mars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll throw an answer out here, just to see if anybody comes up with an earlier one.  In Justice League of America Volume 1, Issue 12 June 62, Dr Light sends the JLA to a variety of "sidereal" worlds calculated to bring about their demise.  GA gets sent to one where the entire planet is a magnet for wood so he can't even lift is bow and arrows.[image]